# After I moved files from my hard disk to my new folder from help of geek squad, my administator's folder name is changed, how do I changed it back?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, user-accounts, administrator, user-folders

So my old laptop crashed, and I was lucky enough to get a new laptop with no cost. With help from geek squad, they were able to moved all the files from my old laptop to my new laptop. The username that displayed on my screen is Thomas(my name) when I log in. But under my C local user drives, the administator's folder is Sarah(my mom's name since the warranty was under her account from the company). I created a new user folder there too called Thomas, but it is not the adminstator's folder and I can't access it fro my document.

1) I typed whoami under command prompt and it says my admin account is sarah, but if that's true why is my laptop displaying my name when I log in?

2) Is there a way to change the admin folder name from sarah to Thomas? I tried to regedit thing and change the value to Thomas, but I was not able to login to my account,very scary! Luckily I logged into a temporary account and changed the value back and everything is normal again. So is there way to safely change your admin local user folder in windows 10?

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account, make your user an Administrator, then take ownership of the files

Comment: You wanted to change the "username" or the "Display Name"? Because you can have a username of sarah (and shows C:\Users\sarah) but the Display Name of "Thomas".

Comment: I want change username, my display name is my name when I log in. Buy my administrator name and local folder name is Sarah?